# In asterisk, How can I restrict caller to press particular key as DTMFinstead of all?

Tags: asterisk, dtmf, agi

I made a call flow using php AGI in asterisk. For getting DTMF from caller, I have user **fastpass_get_data()** function of AGI. In this function caller can press any key. As and when caller press any key, playing prompt will be stoped.

Now I want that when caller press "1" at that time only that playing prompt will stop. So while prompt file is playing and user press any digit except "1", it will not affect playing file. But if user press "1" playing prompt file file should be stopped and call flow continue onwards.

Thanks !!!

Answer (score 0):

Use streamfile command

```
stream file Usage: STREAM FILE <filename> <escape digits> [sample offset]

Send the given file, allowing playback to be interrupted by the given digits, if any.

Use double quotes for the digits if you wish none to be permitted.

If sample offset is provided then the audio will seek to sample offset before play starts.

Remember, the file extension must not be included in the filename.

Returns: failure: 200 result=-1 endpos=<sample offset> failure on open: 200 result=0 endpos=0 success: 200 result=0 endpos=<offset> digit pressed: 200 result=<digit> endpos=<offset>
```

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/stream+file

Comment: If we use Stream File, There is no option to wait for particular Timeout. In fastpass_get_data() function, it will wait for 3 seconds after prompt completed to allow caller to insert DTMF. So no such timeout available in streamfile().

Comment: "escape digits" are digits which stop playback. There are no any timeout in streamfile. You can add silence after playback if you need delay after end of play